# How to automatically apply some conditions on a model in its class using Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to apply some conditions on my models (after retrieving from the database), I found this approach but it has a problem that is for before getting relations and the model has no relations but I want them.

```
    public static function booted()
    {
        static::retrieved(function (Product $product) // $product has no relations even if use 'with' method.
        {
            // Something that I want to do on my all products to check something on them. (not on a specific field, on entire product) 
            $product->check = new ProductCheck($product);
        });
    }
```

I always want to map on my collection (or when I get just one product with `first` method) automatically.

Manually, I have to do this each time I get a product or a collection of products:

```
$products = Product::with('attributes')->get();

$products = $products->map(function ($product) {
     $product->check = new ProductCheck($product);
     return $product;
});

// Or

$product = Product::with('attributes')->find(1);
$product->check = new ProductCheck($product);
```

But I want to do this inside the Product model that don't need to repeat it each time I get products and the closest approach I found was the `static::retrieved` that does not solve my problem.

Is ther any methods inside models classes that I can map my data after retrieving with relations from the database and before I get them with `get` or `first` or any methods like these?

Comment: Your question is very cryptic. Try to explain with a better example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Look into model events. That example got you on the right track. A `->get()` will get you a **collection**, so, for **each** of the collection, do you want to do something? Or **transform** your database records into another **resource**?

Comment: yes sorry, I tried to make it better

Answer (score 1):

you can use `retrieved` event like this :

```
static::retrieved(function (Product $product) 
    {
        $product->setAttribute('check',new ProductCheck($product));
    });
```

Comment: Yes I did this, but that has a problem, I will use the `attributes` relation related to the product inside `ProductCheck` class, so `$product` in retrieved method does not have the relations with itself and will make a new request to database for each one and its not a good thing. I want `$product` model after retrieving relations.

Answer (score 1):

How about using scope in model??

Add following code in Product model

```
public function scopeCheck($query) { 
    // Write your restriction here 
    return $query->where('active', 1); 
}
```

In controller:

```
$products = Product::check()->get();
```